# Copying logic bricks causes acts strange in the logic editor

Tags: game-engine, logic-bricks

I copied some logic bricks from object 1 to object 2.

Now everytime I pick only object 1 or only object 2, both their SCAs appear on the logic brick menu. It is exhausting since they are many. Why is this happening and how do I stop it?

Comment: Without knowing your setup I can't investigate.

Comment: Here is the blend flie : http://www.pasteall.org/blend/37603
Try to paste the flashlight's logic bricks to the "nightvision googles" and then just select 1 of them.  P.S. some models used are not mine, but share by dewhead24 and Wayward art company.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you copy inter-object connections, they will be preserved.

[image]

The result is (when enabled) that you see indirectly connected objects too, not just direct connected objects.

[image]

You can switch of indirect links:

[image]

Comment: ok got it. But if I don't copy them, and redo all the SCAs from scatch, even with link activated I won't be able to see them right?

Comment: If you do it exactly as the other, you would still need to create the inter-object connection. The result would be the same. -> the question is: do you really want the exact copy?